# Use mulching blades without deflector

Tags: lawn-mower

If you use mulching blades on a ZTR mower without a deflector that mounts underneath the deck, what would happen? I had thought about getting mulching blades, but the deflector piece made of plastic cost three times the cost of all the blades combined.[image]

Comment: This is exactly how I use my zero-turn Cub Cadet because the plug won't stay in the discharge. It discharges the grass just like normal blades and I find I like the result of the lawn without the plug more than with it.

Comment: Ok. I have two questions. The plug on yours would be equivalent to plastic deflector on mine. Is that correct. Also, if you are cutting thick area of grass where it tends to leave grass laying on the ground, should I cut it high first and then lower it? ( I cut once a week, so it doesn’t ever get too high, but I do tend to have places where grass piles up)

Comment: I believe that is correct. My grass grows quick so there is always grass on the ground, I only mow once but try to mow so that it isn't a significant amount, or if I mow a day or so before rain the rain seems to clean a lot of that up. I haven't had good experience cutting it twice, it just seems to move the pile rather than "re-mulch" it.

Comment: How much difference did you see with regular blades vs mulching blades without plug?

Comment: I'm not sure that it made a lot of difference, the bigger difference for me was fixing the deflector so that it was up and would distribute the grass more. You'll probably need to play around with your particular set up to get it how you want it.

Comment: Ok. So it it was all the way up, it would distribute it best. Just in case you wondered, the pic in my original posting shows what i was talking about that mounts under the mower deck. If I am not mistaken, the deflector you are talking about is the one that mounts on the side of the mower deck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79011/discussion-between-georgia-guy-and-ron-beyer).